# difference between store(x, std::memory_order_relaxed) and directly assigning a value

Tags: c++, atomic

For the code below, there is only write operation, no read-modify-write, is there any difference between `store` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` and assign value directly?

```
std::atomic<int> x;
int y;

x.store(123, std::memory_order_relaxed)
y = 123
```

Comment: `int y;` should probably be `std::atomic<int> y;`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, memory ordering is only relevant in the context of multiple
`load()`/`store()` operations.
It is difficult be give a precise answer about the differences in what could
be seen before/after when only a `store()` operation is shown.

According to
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order 
`memory_order_relaxed`: *"there are no synchronization or ordering constraints
imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's atomicity is guaranteed"*

So, the only difference between `store()` with `std::memory_order_relaxed`
and a simple assignment is the **guaranteed atomicity**.

That being said, when it comes to the specificities of the platforms,
we could very often observe that even a simple assignment of an integer
is atomic (i.e. it won't change a few bytes first, and a few others later
in a way that could be seen by another thread for example).
But the C++ standard does not guarantee that and another specific
hardware could decide to behave differently on that purpose.

Comment: Some platforms / compilers *may* guarantee atomicity even for plain store of non-atomic, though it is out of standard C++ scope.

Comment: Most importantly, conflicting operations (that is, concurrent operations where at least one is a write, which are not ordered by a happens-before relation) on a non-atomic variable result in _undefined behavior_.